# Jquery Php get data and read

Tags: php, jquery, maps

I use google maps and dynamic store. When I was paste code in manually, my map is working. When I use to ajax / get method my map is not working.
I see this in the console log for my php data

```
var  locations =   
    $.ajax({
        url:"mapquery.php",
        method:"post",
        beforeSend:function(){ },                    
            success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
    },});
```

Comment: Format your code first and supply more info!

Comment: insert orijinal code

Answer (score 0):

**orijinal code**

```
var locations = [
[ locationData('single-property-page-1.html','$275,000','$520 / sq ft','images/listing-01.jpg','Eagle Apartmets',"9364 School St. Lynchburg, NY "), 40.7427837, -73.11445617675781, 1, markerIcon ],
            [ locationData('single-property-page-1.html','$900','monthly','images/listing-02.jpg','Serene Uptown',"6 Bishop Ave. Perkasie, PA"), 40.70437865245596, -73.98674011230469, 2, markerIcon ],
...
...
...]
```

**my code ;**

```
 var  locations =   
$.ajax({
url:"mapquery.php",
method:"post",
beforeSend:function(){ },
success:function(respon){
console.log(respon);},});
```

**Mapquery.php**

```
    [ [ locationData("https://profile/82","150","","https://userpicture/1544126707_img_1819.jpg","Old School","adasd, asdasd, asdasd, asafasf"),45.042 , 39.006014, 1, markerIcon ]
...]
```